# How do I find/set the scratch buffer location?

Tags: emacs, buffer, default, aquamacs

In my Aquamacs the scratch buffer has a file location where I can save random notes, and it's located in
`USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/scratch buffer`

I'd like to sync this with my other emacsen, but I can't find where (or *if*) the scratch buffer for 'normal' Emacs is saved.

**Edit**
Thanks, Slomojo. I ended up putting this in my .emacs and it works as hoped:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/scratch buffer")
```

I think the Aquamacs philosophy of the *scratch buffer* is just different from that of 'normal' emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal `*scratch*` buffer in Emacs isn't a file, it's just a memory buffer.

Of course, you can save it to a file, or have your `.emacs` load an alternative to `*scratch*` from an actual file at startup.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the default variable in aquamacs is called aquamacs-scratch-file, so you should better add to your .emacs :

(setq aquamacs-scratch-file "~/scratch")